# How to get desktop version of webpage under Android?

Tags: java, android

I try to get webpage using `HttpURLConnection`, and get a result of mobile version page.

Now I want to get a desktop version page, and try to use: `System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0");` or `setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0");` But I still get a result of mobile version page.

Does anyone know how to get a desktop version source code of webpage instead the mobile version?

PS: My Android is 2.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the User-Agent of your connection to pretend that it's a desktop client.

As you are using the HttpUrlConnection, you can do something like:

```
URL url = new URL( "http://www.google.co.in/" );
HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty( "User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
```

Comment: Yes, I do like that. But I can't get desktop version.