# Need Mobile Device to Open Desktop Version of Site

Tags: mobile, desktop

There's a review site out there that when you open the site in the desktop version, you can leave reviews for a particular company but then when you visit the mobile version of the site, there is an option to read reviews but not to leave a review.

I'd like to send a user to a link (reviewourcompany.com) and when they visit that link with their smartphone, it opens up the desktop version for them to leave a review.

Is this possible?

Comment: I certainly hope not.

Comment: Or any other workarounds would be acceptable as well. I just need the user to access the desktop version of the site rather than the mobile version.

Comment: Try this [How to get desktop version of webpage under Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211818/how-to-get-desktop-version-of-webpage-under-android)

Answer (score 0):

If the site is using the URL itself to determine which version to display, just send the "desktop" version.  If, as is more likely, it is querying information provided by the user's *browser* to determine which version to display, you are out of luck.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's using the browser. Would using the browser be the same as querying the device? There's no way to force it to show the desktop version at all? Admittedly I'm not a coder so I don't know myself. I was hoping there was a way for the URL to send the request and make the website think it was a desktop computer, laptop, or just a larger size screen.

Comment: That depends on the site.

Comment: plus.google.com

I'd like to have the smartphone user be directed to the desktop version.

Comment: Since using the same URL from 2 different devices yields different versions, if there is a way to force the desktop version via the URL, it isn't clear what to add to the URL to do this.

Comment: I should have also mentioned this, we use a redirect, like a ourbiz.com that when put into the browser, redirects them to the page. Could we put something in the redirect to force them to show the desktop version of the site?

Comment: Since a redirect is just another URL, the same issues apply.