# How to get the content of a desktop version website in android?

Tags: java, android, url

I use the following code to get the content of a url, but I find in android and in my pc the result is different. How can I get the desktop version content in android?

```
URL url = new URL("https://xxx");
InputStream in = url.openStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader bufr = new BufferedReader(isr);
String str;
while ((str = bufr.readLine()) != null) {xxx}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211818/how-to-get-desktop-version-of-webpage-under-android

Comment: great! It's solved